# Passe data in bundle to the activity of the gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I had this code, without the bundle it works very well, but when I add the bundle in the intent, in my `onActivityResult` I don't found this `id_q` in data, I found just the path of the chosen picture.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("id_q", q.getId());
        intent.putExtras(b);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

this is **onActivityResult** :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
```

and in **onSelectFromGalleryResult**(data) I had this :

```
       if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            int id_q = b.getInt("id_q");}
```

Comment: Why don't you set id_q as a global variable and then you can use in your whole activity.

Comment: the code in loop, I can't use global variable

Comment: Ohh ! so mean you are calling the multiple startActvityForResult inside for loop?

Comment: I had a loop of questions and I will add a file from gallery to the chosen question so there's why I did that

Comment: Can you show us the loop in your code so we better understand how it doesn't let you store your int in a variable ?

Comment: Ok but still your "id_q" not in the picture. I am assuming that your code is something like this.
for(you loop){
// Intent
// start activity
}

Is this your code something like this?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper yes it looks like that

Comment: In this case you just have to reassign your variable in the loop. Something like that for(you loop){ id_q = q.getId(); // Intent // start activity }

Comment: AFAIK if you are passing value from intent which actually pick image from gallery never return the your bundle value because from the gallery intent create a new intent and pass it to the onActivityResult so your value was vanish and never get back to you.

Comment: So, there's a solution for this or a workaround ?

Comment: and how I can passe the id ?,, cause I need to store the data with this id

Comment: You just have your id_q global so it is accessible from onActivityResult

Comment: no cause it's a loop, if I put it global, I'll get only the last one, thank's anyway dude

Comment: @Euphor08 if you do this your startActivityForResult call n number of time of your for loops and may be your app got crash.

Comment: I don't know what to expect from startActivityForResult in a loop. I would rather check if the list of questions is empty or not in onActivityResult and call startActivityForResult again there

Comment: @Euphor08 see my post.This is the hint how you can achieve it no issue with this answer. Please let me know your reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, I would suggest something like this.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Question> questionsLeft;

    Question currentQ;

    /* ... */

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                // Do what you have to do with data and currentQ
                processNext();
            }
        }
    }

    public void processNext() {
        if(questionsLeft.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        currentQ = questionsLeft.get(0);
        questionsLeft.remove(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

You can also have one requestCode for each question in your list. You will know that your request is "SELECT_IMAGE" if it is in a given range instead of a single value.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to assign the **id_q** you can achieve it like this way.

> Step 1: Create a global variable lets say **int counter = 0;** and
>   also the arraylist or list whatever you taken for your ids. lets say for e.g.

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList;
```

> Step 2: Now, Call your Intent to choose image inside for loop

For E.g

```
For loop (up to your n number of size)
{
  // Now Call your intent here.
}
```

> Step 3: Inside your OnActivityResult in your
>   **onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);**

int id_q = yourArrayList.get(counter);

increase the size of Counter.

counter++;

Now, you don't need to do anything further once you pick one by one image from Gallery it comes to startActivityResult and you will get all the ids and your counter increases too so you got all the new values from arrayList from particular position.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: thank's for the response, I saw the other one before yours, I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

On activity result is called in the activity from which you are calling the startActivityForResult();

As you are using the chooser in this case it is not necessary that the result intent will contain the same information as you are adding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, How I passe the data ?

Comment: Can you explain where do you want to pass the data?

Comment: I will open the gallery with bundle who has a specific id_q and when I come back to my activity (after picking the image from gallery) I want find the path of image and the id_q, clear ?

Comment: You dont need to send it in bundle then take a normal int in your activity and assign it the value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

There is no need of a Bundle here.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putIntExtra("id_q", q.getId());
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

and in **onActivityResult**

```
int id_q = data.getIntExtra("id_q");
```

Comment: No, it's wrong, how you can find the id_q if you don't passe it first ?

Comment: `intent.putIntExtra()` passes the data along with the intent and `intent.getIntExtra()` gets the data.